# how to create full width figure in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I want to display figure that use the full browser width in blogdown posts (I'm using the academic theme), as the l-screen-inset layout for the [distill blog](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/figures.html):

[image]
I guess this is related to how R Markdown file is rendered as html. So is this full-width setting possible in R Markdown by assigning some specific css class to a contianer without the distill framework? Or is there some way that hugo / blogdown could display such full-width figure?